# Hiding div behind its parent?

Tags: css, css-position, css-transitions

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="close">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.content-wrapper is relatively positioned and contains all the page content (not just the popup).

.popup is absolutely positioned.

.close is also absolutely positioned.

I have some javascript to move close when the cursor enters popup (so I have a nice close bar appear out the side). The best way I have found to do this is just to move using jQuery animate. Hiding/showing creates a stuttering affect even .stop() wasn't able to solve. My problem is in trying to hide .close behind .popup. No matter what z-index I set for the two divs .close will not sit behind .popup.

Is it possible to have an absolutely positioned div inside another absolutely positioned div sit behind its parent, and if so how?

Comment: changing markup is an option?

Comment: Possibly, the popup moves around the screen (hence why it's absolutely positioned), so having the close inside the popup was the only solution I could think of. If better markup will work then I'm willing to try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, use z-index: http://jsfiddle.net/tGd4Q/

HTML:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="close">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.popup, .close { position: absolute; height: 200px; width: 200px; }
.popup { background: #f00; }
.close { background: #ff0; top: 25px; left: 25px; z-index: -1; }​
```

This won't work with IE7 standards though. I suggest using jQuery(or other framework of your choosing) to hide the div:

```
$('.popup .close').hide();
```

Comment: I see it works in jsfiddle, but that doesn't work in my code.

Comment: It works, but only if you have .close set to -1 and .popup not set at all. Any other combination and it doesn't, weird. Works for my purposes though, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Stacking indices are most of the time relative to siblings, so you cannot put a child behind it's parent using `z-index`.

[Here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/) is some more information about that.

This is the stacking order:

1. The borders and background of the current stacking context
2. Positioned descendants with negative z-index
3. Nonpositioned block-level descendants with no z-index property defined -- paragraphs, tables, lists, and so on
4. Floating descendants and their contents
5. Nonpositioned inline content
6. Positioned descendants with no z-index, z-index: auto, or z-index: 0
7. Positioned descendants with z-index greater than 0

Nick McCormack uses `z-index: -1` in his answer. This is indeed one exception to what your feelings give in. Beware that `z-index: -1` moves an element behind **many of** your elements to the background.

### Browser differences

Beside that, Internet Explorer does not support negative stacking indices and is very strict with element (child/parent) positions. Every element level has it's own stacking context, so have to 'communicate' via the parent element. See [this explanation](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/).

According to [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/), the `select` element, which is a windowed control, has naturally a higher stacking index.

According to the [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/options.html) `troubleElement` option, I presume that `object`, `embed` and `canvas` have the same issues.

---

If you want to hide `.close`, why don't you really hide it instead of moving it behind `.popup`?

```
$('.close').hide();
```

Comment: How does -1 function on different browsers?  Do you know?

Comment: When I tried to use .show and .hide the css positioning of the object got screwed up. It would stutter like mad then move to left 0 all the time.

Comment: -1 works in everything but IE7, but isn't a good solution to this dilemma. The 'right' solution isn't a CSS one unfortunately, but alas, it is what the question asks.

Comment: @Styphon: show and hide of what object? If your `.close` is positioned absolute, this should not influence the position of the other elements in the `.popup`. Be sure that you always give up a horizontal and vertical position to absolute positioned elements, otherwise IE is confused.

Comment: @Clarence Klopfstein: I updated my answer with some information about other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to put it behind its parent.  However you could change its display mode to none, so it isn't seen at all.  Then when you need to see the div, change it to show.

Simple jQuery:

```
$('.close').hide();
$('.close').show();
```

There are other ways as well, such as adding an attribute of style with `display:none` or `display: inline-block` as a setting.

**Update**: According to comments in other answers, there IS a way to do it with z-index.  Still thinking the hide/show is the way to go though.  Very clear what you are doing on your UI.

Comment: Simply using .hide and .show creates a bouncing effect. If I then use .stop() to stop the bouncing it doesn't show at all.

Comment: Please add more sample HTML, as this example would be hard to see any bouncing.