# Z-index and multiple dropdowns

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index

I'm adding a new dropdown div to an existing WordPress theme with it's own dropdown menu.

The new dropdown is activated and "dropping down" from an area above the menu.

The menu is set to z-index:99, but whatever value i give "my dropdown", the menu still appears on top of it.

Only exception is if i give the menu z-index:0, then all works fine except that the menu's dropdowns, of course, does not overlap items further down the page :/

Help appreciated!

Update: I have tried different position values, the menu needs to be "relative" to work.

The dropdown is now absolute, but relative gives the same result.

Comment: Post some code so we can take a look.

Comment: Added a link to my post now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following declared in your `styles.css` stylesheet on `line: 316`:

```
#section-tophat, #section-footer, #section-sub-footer { position: relative;  z-index: 1;  } /* Setup for :after double bgs below */
```

You're setting your `#section-tophat` to `z-index:1` and thus at a lower level than your menu, so just remove your `#section-tophat` id from that line and your dropdown works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're a hero!

Didn't write this Css myself and for some reason i missed that when looking in Firebug :)

Answer (score 0):

**z-index** only work on position `relative`, `absolute` & `fixed`. So, give `position:relative` to your `dropdown` DIV.

Comment: Thank you. That have solved such problems before so i a already tried both relative & absolute with no luck...

The menu is position:relative, and that can't be changed without breaking the theme...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an example page that we can check? You also may have stacking context issues.

Check [my answer about how `z-index` works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030386/hiding-div-behind-its-parent/10030479#10030479).